# Do I need to have a compatible graphics card to develop with the latest version of OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, graphics, driver, updates

I want to write a program with OpenGL version 4. The currently installed version of OpenGL is 2.1.0 on my computer. I checked for a way to install the latest version of OpenGL, but in online articles it is said that the only way of updating OpenGL libraries is by updating the graphics card driver software.

I have a laptop with *Mobile Intel(R) 4 Series Express Chipset Family* graphics card. The last update was released in 2010, and it looks like to be abandoned.

Is it possible to write high version OpenGL software with a bad graphics card? I don't care if my program will be running with low FPS rate or be very sluggish on my hardware. I just would like to know if it is technically possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your graphics card must support the OpenGL 4 version to develop with it. It is mandatory that the hardware (graphic card) is compatible with the OpenGl version you want to develop and the driver installed in your system allows the graphic card to use that version.

Supported cards for openGL 4 (Wikipedia):

> Nvidia GeForce 400 series, Nvidia GeForce 500 series, Nvidia GeForce
>   600 series, Nvidia GeForce 700 series, ATI Radeon HD 5000 Series, AMD
>   Radeon HD 6000 Series, AMD Radeon HD 7000 Series. Supported by Intel's
>   Windows drivers for the Haswell's integrated GPU.

In your case your graphic card and driver only allows openGl 2.1.

Nowadays almost any graphic card for 40/50 Euros is capable to run openGl 4 (but change it on the laptop usually is not possible)

For more information check [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL) and [Nvidia](https://developer.nvidia.com/opengl-driver)

Comment: unless you want to use a (slow as molasses) software implementation